# How to call ASPX page from CLASS (Inside Class)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i want to call or Redirect ASPX page from CLASS File or inside function of class
please help me or give Hint for that or 
Please write the statement for call or Redirect ASPX page from or in side Class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply do  :

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/myPage.aspx")
```

notice 2 things please :

1) you can use the tilde (~) to indicate the root of application

2) this (by default) will raise thread abort exception .you can eliminate it by olverload the method with `false`.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/myPage.aspx",false)
```

3) you should add `using System.Web;`

Answer (score 0):

You CLASS should derive from System.Web.UI.Page, inside your class you can use this below method

```
HttpResponse.Redirect(string url)
```